# Jr or Jnr for describing Junior job position?

Tags: abbreviations

What is the correct way to abbreviate Junior when describing a job position

Jr ,JR or Jnr, JNR? or is it best to just write Junior

I have always thought Jr was used after someones name but have seen some people use it to describe their position.

Comment: I would say "Junior" unless you have a really compelling reason to have to abbreviate it.

Comment: I have never seen "junior" abbreviated as "jnr".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junior would be more appropriate; save 'Jr', 'Jnr' etc. for 'John Smith Jnr, son of John Smith Snr'